# How to access servlet attribute in GWT server side code?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I've assembled my GWT app as war file which I am running in embedded Jetty-

```
String confFile = System.getProperty("configFilename");
config = new XMLConfiguration(configFilename);
Server server = new Server(8080);
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setAttribute("config", config);      
webapp.setContextPath("/");
webapp.setWar("file.war");
server.setHandler(webapp);
server.start();
server.join();
```

I am trying to access my "config" object in GWT server side code-

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        MyService {

    config = (XMLConfiguration) this.getThreadLocalRequest().getAttribute("config");

}
```

Here, config is always null.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried  `config =(XMLConfiguration) this.getServletContext().getAttribute("config");` but that doesn't work too - I get error-

```
org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration
```

Comment: That error tells me that you must have the XMLConfiguration class in 2 separate jars.  One is probably deployed as part of Jetty and the other as part of your app.

Comment: @LavieTobey - that is correct

Comment: Are you using maven for dependency managements?

Comment: Try specifically importing that jar and marking it as provided and see if that cast works.

Comment: just tried- didn't work :( same error

Comment: @LavieTobey I tried setting provided as scope in maven and it worked- it didn't work in Eclipse for some reason but it did in Netbeans. If you can put your comment as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting your maven dependencies to explicitly include the jar containing the XMLConfiguration class and marking it as provided.  This will remove the duplicate in your classpath and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the attribute from the `ServletContext` instead of from the `HttpServletRequest`

Try this inside your RPC method:

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyService {

  @Override
  public void MyMethod() {
     this.getThreadLocalRequest()
         .getSession().getServletContext()
         .getAttribute("config");
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried- I get error `org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration`

Comment: Very odd that the same class is not casteable to itself. It seems like you are using different versions of the XMLConfiguration class when launching jetty, and then in your .war

Comment: Check your dependency tree and look for commons-configuration, proly you have two version of this library. `mvn dependency:tree`